# Finding volume of a solid about a vertical line

Tags: calculus

How can I calculate the volume of the solid generated by rotating the region bounded by

$y=x^2-6x+10$

and

$y=-x^2+4x+2$

About the line **$x=4$**

Comment: Have you tried the cylindrical shells method?

Comment: was my answer helpful? If not, please comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cylindrical shells.

Your representative rectangle would be vertical, and its width is  $dx$ and its height is $$-x^2 +4x + 2 - (x^2 -6x + 10) = -2x^2 + 10x - 8 $$

Now, construct your integral:

$$2\pi\int_{1}^4 p(x)h(x)dx$$

$p(x) = 4-x$ since you're rotating around the line $x = 4$

$$2\pi\int_{1}^4 (4-x)*(-2x^2 + 10x - 8)dx = \frac{27\pi}{2}$$

comment if you need more help.

Comment: so to find the height $h(x)$ you simply subtract the top polynomial from the bottom?

Comment: @user8028 not always, but in this case yes. Take a look at the graphs. I'm sure you can see why I did this. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+x%5E2%E2%88%926*x%2B10%2C+y%3D%E2%88%92x%5E2%2B4*x%2B2

Comment: @VarunIyer: I did a plot about this by Maple. Woul you like me to add them in your post? :-)

Comment: You are then welcome to if you'd like I have grasped the concept though